# Filtering dataset to only show the data within a range of values

Tags: r, function, statistics

How do I remove data within a dataframe which is not included within my range? My dataframe which contains the information is called `df` and contains a start and end point:

```
start  end
65     1237
1262   2134
2178   4511
.....
```

I am trying to filter through results in another df, `n`, to only show the rows in V1 which fall between the start and end points in `df`. `n` looks like:

```
V1    V2
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
```

I have wrote this function so far, which I am wanting to apply to `n`, however, the code does not do anything when typing in T_filter(n) in the console. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
T_filter <- function(x) {
   T_range=c(df$start: df$end)
   T_range = sort(T_range)
   tmp = tmp[ T_range , ]
   tmp = tmp[!is.na(tmp$V1),]
  }}
```

Comment: `n[n$V1 > df$start & n$V1 < df$end, ]`. You can use `>=` and `<=` if you want the range to be inclusive. This assumes you want your range applied line by line, that is each row of `n` corresponds to a row of ranges in `df`.

Comment: This does not seem to include all the ranges within my dataset. I am wanting to get the outputs of V1 which are included within the ranges generated from df. For example all the rows in between 65 and 1237.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(\(x,y) n[x:y, ], df$start, df$end))
```

It's mapping the columns in parallel, and using those to subset the rows